# user defined functions vs built in function in java five relevant differences over time and space complexities

Tags: java, function

Please explain me the differences over time and space complexities in java for user defined and predefined functions in java. examples like, linked list, list, stack class. please explain this with valid example.
thank you.

Comment: Which user defined function? which in-built function?. It depends on how you implement things / algorithms. Thats it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing special in predefined function over user defined. The only thing is predefined has been written by somebody else for you. It depends on algorithm.

Comment: Does this make difference, while considering time and space complexities?

Answer (score 0):

Crap code/implementation runs in a crap way. Doesn't matter if its user created or system/API provided. example at a high level is EJBs vs Spring.

Good written code runs pretty and sleek. Again doesn't matter who the hell wrote it.